# My UPDATE SQL statement results in a syntax error

Tags: mysql

The code is to update a MySQL database table.

```
 $sql = "UPDATE test
            SET EmailID = :EmailID,
              Localite = :Localite,
              Nom = :Nom,
              Statut = :Statut,
            WHERE EmailID = :EmailID";
```

The error is:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE EmailID = 'haha@haha.com''

There should not have been any error displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the comma after `Statut = :Statut,`

```
$sql = "UPDATE test
        SET EmailID = :EmailID,
            Localite = :Localite,
            Nom = :Nom,
            Statut = :Statut
        WHERE EmailID = :EmailID";
```